# chrome extension payments no oauth setup link for oauth tokens

Tags: google-chrome-extension, oauth, payment, chrome-web-store

I have a chrome extension that i am building that I would like to accept payment for.

I am following the instructions laid out by Google in the [Chrome Web Store docs](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/get_started).

I have followed them up to the point where I am supposed to be able to get the Oauth token. I do not have a button anywhere in my developer dashboard for the extension.

Comment: Developer _console_? You should be looking at your Dashboard in CWS.

Comment: Yes, that is where I am.  chrome web store - developer dashboard - sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I made this much more complicated than it actually was.  I followed these directions for the [One-Time-Payment](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/one_time_payments#verifying-payment).